# Magento getAttribute not working with listing product

Tags: magento

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

This code is not working fine in `view.phtml` it is not return first attribute code value.

when i write this code on view page, it is not showing first product attribute and all after first in loop are showing fine.

This is my all code

```
<?php

$productAttributeTh = array('Color','Item','Size');

$configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$configurableProduct);   

foreach($childProducts as $child) {
$product_id =  $child->getId();

$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$_childProduct = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id

foreach ($productAttributeTh as $key => $productAttributeValue){ 
$productAttribute = $_childProduct->getResource()->getAttribute($productAttributeValue)->getFrontend()->getValue($_childProduct);

echo $productAttribute;
}

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your attribute is set to be used in list.  Go to;

```
Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes
```

Find your attribute, and open it.  Scroll down to the option 'used in product listing' and set it 'yes'.  Save and then reindex attributes.

Comment: it is 'yes' i have checked

Comment: i take it $attribute is defined in the list view?

Comment: yes $attribute gives attribute name like color,item,size

Comment: difficult to bug test without your full code, but try this instead; echo $_product->getAttributeText($attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

Or

```
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

i hope this will help you.